# Plot summary of community data in R by metadata category

Tags: r, metadata, categories

I think this is a very basic question, but I have spent several hours searching for an answer but am not able to apply what I find to my specific problem.

I have two tables:

1. a community data table in which each row is a the proportion of species in each site and each row is the site, and…
2. a metadata table in which each row is a site and each column is a category describing some attribute of the site.

Very simply I would like to summarize the community data by a specific category of the metadata. How would I make a simple barplot of the relative contribution of each species in sites summarized by category? Perhaps:

```
barplot(commData, metadata$category)
```

Comment: Its always easier and faster to get help when you provide some data aka a reproducible example..A few rows of both tables (community data and metadata) will do. Doesn't have to be the real data, dummies will do. cheers.

Comment: See [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on improving your question.